# jquery.hotkeys.js replaces input field with .bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor, hotkeys

I'm using [jquery.hotkeys.js](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) and mapping my keybinding in the following fashion:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'i', function() {
      $("input#foo").focus()
});
```

Yet, after calling focus (in attempts to try and move the cursor to the end of the input field when hitting key `i` being focused on the document) it simply replaces the content of the input field with `i`. It's possible to prevent the total replacement, however, the `i` still gets appended even after doing so. Example:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'i', function() {
      var val = $("input#foo").val()
      $("input#foo").focus()
      $("input#foo").val(val.substring(0,val.length-1)
});
```

In this case, an input of `television` would turn into `televisioi`. Anyone of know any workarounds possible? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the default functionality by passing the event:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'i', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("input#foo").focus();
});
```

I imagine you'll want to prevent the keyup functionality too:

```
$(document).bind('keyup', 'i', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```